Algorithm to get prev/next date in the interval
(examples are in zig, but I guess this is a general noob algorithmic question)
Let's say we have a date
const Date = struct {
    year: u16,
    month: u4, //Jan=1,Dec=12
    day: u5,
};

And something is supposed to happen at the regular intervals (aka every y years, m months and d days)
const Interval = struct {
    years: i16,
    years_offset: i16,
    months: i16,
    months_offset: i16,
    days: i16,
    days_offset: i16,
};

note that months and days may be not restricted. I could say something should happend every 5 years, 23 months and 374 days, for example.
When determening a next date, let's say days are shifted first (so we need to take into accound numbers of days in starting months), then months and years are shifted without changing the day (check if we end up in 30th of february or something like that only at the end).
If I have a date that may be not aligned to the interval, how do I get a previous/next date that is aligned?
For example - something is supposed to happend every 2 months and 3 day since Jan 4, 2024, so the dates are:

2024.01.04
2024.03.07
2024.05.10
2024.07.13

And I have a 2024.06.01. How do I get previous (2024.05.10) and next (2024.07.13) dates?
(note: Date does have shiftDays/shiftMonths/shiftYears methods that may help, or helper functions to check for isLeapYear(year), .daysInMonth() but nothing more complicated).

If I understand correctly:

You have an event that happens at known regular intervals of the form { d days + m months + y years }.
You know one date, call it KnownEventDate, on which this event occurs.

You don't seem to mention anything like this in the question, but it's clearly necessary, so I assume you have it.


You already know how to add and subtract this interval; so, given a date on which this event occurs, you already know how to compute earlier and later dates on which it occurs.
You have some date of interest, call it DateOfInterest, on which this event may or may not occur.
Of all dates on which this event occurs, you want to find the ones that directly precede and follow DateOfInterest.

So, I actually don't think you're going to do better than the naive algorithm that starts with KnownEventDate and adds or subtracts Interval until it finds the neighbors of DateOfInterest:
set EventDate := KnownEventDate
while EventDate < DateOfInterest:
  EventDate := EventDate.PlusInterval(Interval)
while EventDate > DateOfInterest:
  EventDate := EventDate.MinusInterval(Interval)
-- EventDate is now the latest event-date <= DateOfInterest
if EventDate == DateOfInterest:
  return [EventDate.MinusInterval(Interval), EventDate.PlusInterval(Interval)]
else:
  return [EventDate, EventDate.PlusInterval(Interval)]

The reason for this is that your intervals aren't really regular intervals; they sound regular because we're so used to the Gregorian calendar that "one month" (really "one Gregorian calendar month") feels like a real unit of time, but in fact it varies between 28 and 31 days. (And Gregorian calendar years, likewise, can be either 365 or 366 days.) So your PlusInterval and MinusInterval methods need to take into account the vagaries of the Gregorian calendar, which depend on the specific year and what point in the year you are. As a result, there's no real logic to identify whether a given date has the event, other than applying the calculations and repeatedly adjusting based on the rules of the Gregorian calendar.
Note that that's because the intervals combine days and months. If they were defined only in days, or only in months and years, then you could do much better. It's the combination that's the killer, due to the irregular relationship between the two.
(By the way, this is neither here nor there, but I have to admit that I'm not sure what 2024-01-31 plus one month would be. My best guess is that we add 31 days because January has 31 days; but it feels weird that a day in January, plus one month, is a day in March. Real-world monthly events don't work like that.)
